# Wordpress - Including page title in 'wp get attachment image'

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, I've set up a bit of code which searching for all the pages which are a child of the ID 8, then outputs all the attachments (in the gallery) of these pages as unordered list items. You can see the effect so far here http://goo.gl/eq4UF.

The problem I'm having is that I need to include the title of each page before each  so you can easily identify which images come below which page. Normally I would just add this in, but the list items al use masonry and are positioned all over the page using some JS so they never appear beside the first image in the list.

I therefore will add the title of the page to every
`<li>` in the `<ul>` which will allow the title to run with each image but I don't know how to include this in the wp get attachment image function. Both `the_title` and `wp_title` doesn't work inside this loop. `apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );` obviously takes the image title, but is there any good to take the page title?

Thanks in advance and hope this made sense,
R

```
<?php $postslist = get_pages('number=9999&sort_order=DESC&sort_column=post_date&child_of=8');
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<ul class="main-projects-list">
<?php

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID,
   'orderby' => 'menu_order',
   'order' => 'ASC',
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li class="each-image">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php $postslist = get_pages('number=9999&sort_order=DESC&sort_column=post_date&child_of=8');
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<ul class="main-projects-list">
<?php

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID,
   'orderby' => 'menu_order',
   'order' => 'ASC',
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        $post_title = get_the_title($post->ID); // We get the post title
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           $img_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_title . ' - ' . $attachment->post_title ); // We create the image title with the 2 strings
           echo '<li class="each-image">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' , false, array('title' => $img_title));
           echo '<p>';
           echo $img_title;
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I need the title and the image title as separate variables as I want to load the page title in h2s after li class="each-image". Can you help?

Comment: Managed to just edit what you put together:

            `$main_page_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_title );
      $img_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); 
            echo '<li class="each-image">';
         echo $main_page_title; 
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' , false, array('title' => $img_title));
            echo '<p>';
            echo $img_title;
            echo '</p></li>';`

Comment: Use `$img_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );` to get the image title in a second var. 
Then you can use it in the attachment function this way to get the concatenated string `array('title' => $post_title . ' - ' . $img_title)`, same in the html paragraph below.